# Missing Method Expression

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, export-to-excel

I have built a program using vb 2013 with a datagridview that allows the user to fill out info click submit to my access data base. I also included an export from datagridview to excel. On my machine everything work. On the client the submit to my database base works. However when the client uses the export to excel the program crashes with a Missing Method Exception.  I am new at this so can any one help me solve the Exception below? V

See the end of this message for details on invoking
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.MissingMethodException:

Comment: Are you using Excel interop?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! I am using Excel interop. The code is a little slow but it works on my machine. Thanks for responding David.

Comment: Looks like they have either another Excel or no Excel at all installed.

Comment: It on another corporate machine so we have the same Excel software. The error my test is getting is like this:   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID

Comment: Correct DotNet version installed on the other machines?

Comment: No most clients will not have the dotnet installed on their computer. It's strange the client can pull up the datagridview , filter it with my drop down box, use the datagridview combobox to select items, type in the not field and click save. All changes go back to my access data base on a shared drive. If you go to export the datagridview to excel.... error. Do I need a class to handle excel on other machines? I seen some online chatter that claims that i should lower from net.4.5 to net.3.5. I'm new at this so changing the target whacks out the program all together.

Comment: In a company I assume Win7 as OS so at least dot net 4.0 should work. If you export to Excel XLSX/XLSM File I would use somthing like https://closedxml.codeplex.com/ as it doesn't depend on Excel.

Comment: Thanks David. At a glance the code looks good. It may take awhile for me to convert the C# in to VB.NET.  Just to recap with you the idea here is to export out of the DataGridView via XML and have it convert to XLSX upon opening?

Comment: closedxml has a simnple API to create Excel files on the fly with no need for Excel. So no need need to generate a xml. Just read the data from dgv and write it down